# ¿Como validar con Resquest Laravel sin perder los datos de los inputs en caso de error?

Tags: laravel

Hola buenas tengo una pregunta, etsoy validando un formulario simple como de registro, el problema o la duda que tengo es que si hay un error en la validación no me borre todos los campos ingresados, no estoy ocupando Laravel Collective por lo cual no puedo poner old en el input, estoy haciendolo con inputs tradicionales.

```
      <form action="{{ url('/registro') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rut" placeholder="RUT">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numero" placeholder="Telefono móvil" min="0">
          <p style="text-align: center;"><small><strong>* Te enviaremos un SMS de confirmación para activar tu cuenta</strong></small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <select name="idComoNosConocio" class="form-control">
            <option>Como nos conocio</option>
            @foreach ($comoNosConocio as $conocio)
                <option value="{{ $conocio->idComoNosConocio }}">{{ $conocio->nombreComoNosConocio }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <select name="idTipoUsuarioComercial" class="form-control">
            <option><strong>Quiero ser...</strong></option>
            @foreach ($usuariosComerciales as $usuarioComercial)
                <option value="{{ $usuarioComercial->idTipoUsuarioComercial }}">{{ $usuarioComercial->nombreTipoUsuarioComercial }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="aceptoTerminos"> Acepto los <a href="#">términos</a>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Registrar</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>
```

Otra duda es como puedo validar un checkbox que debe ser marcado a traves del request?

CONTROLADOR

```
DB::beginTransaction();
            $registroUsuario = new Usuario;
            $registroUsuario->rut = $request->rut;
            $registroUsuario->nombre = $request->nombre;
            $registroUsuario->apellido = $request->apellido;
            $registroUsuario->correo = $request->correo;
            $registroUsuario->contrasena = $request->contrasena;
            $registroUsuario->numero = $request->numero;
            $registroUsuario->idTipoUsuario = 2;
            $registroUsuario->tokenParaActivacion = Crypt::encrypt($request->rut);
            if($request->aceptoTerminos){
                $registroUsuario->aceptoTerminos = 1;
            }

            $registroUsuario->idTipoUsuarioComercial = $request->idTipoUsuarioComercial;
            $registroUsuario->idComoNosConocio = $request->idComoNosConocio;
            $registroUsuario->save();

            DB::commit();

            return redirect('/registro');
```

REQUEST

```
return [
            'rut' => 'required|min:9|max:9',
            'nombre'=> 'required|min:3|max:30|',
            'apellido' => 'required|min:3|max:30|',
            'correo' => 'required|email|max:50|',
            'numero' => 'required|min:0',
            'contrasena' => 'required|min:4|max:30'
        ];
```

Debo decir que al registrar funciona, pero cuando meto datos por error que van en contra de las reglas de validación se recarga la página y me obliga a ingresra nuevamente todos los datos a mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El helper `old` no es exclusivo de Laravel collective.

Por ejemplo si yo coloco lo siguiente va a funcionar y posterior a un proceso de validación donde algunos de los datos no *pasaran* entonces este [*helper*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-old) me ayudaría a recuperar dicho valor

```
<input type="text" name="productname" value="{{ old('productname') }}">
```

Lo anterior lo puedes comprobar en la propia [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#old-input)

Comment: Wooo lo probare no sabia, creia que eso era exclusivo de Laravel Collective, gracias :D @Aprendiz

Comment: Me funciono te pasaste :D, muchas gracias. @Aprendiz

Answer (score -2):

Tengo tengo tema pero en un select al momento de fallar la validación se pierde, pongo ejemplo saludos:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> <b>NOMBRE</b>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="nombre" id="general_id" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick">
                                <option>Seleccione un cliente</option>
                                @foreach ($general as $g)
                                <option
                                    data-fecha="{{$g->fecha}}"
                                    data-apellidop="{{$g->apellidop}}"
                                    data-apellidom="{{$g->apellidom}}"
                                    data-calle="{{$g->callev}}"
                                    data-numero="{{$g->numero}}"
                                    data-manzana="{{$g->manzana}}"
                                    data-lote="{{$g->lote}}"
                                    data-cantidad="{{$g->cantidad}}"
                                    value="{{old('nombre')}}"> {{$g->nombre}}
                                </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Esto.. no se entiende que es...